# How do i make text always appear together? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To illustrate the problem better, here's [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwBFPTZtibg) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sr8zjwc/15/).

```
<div class="container-fluid">  
   <div class="container">
     <img src="https://image.com"/>
     <h1>lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
  </div>
```

While window has certain width, one part of text goes under the image and another stays next to it. How can i prevent text from dividing, so when window reaches this certain width, the whole phrase "lorem ipsum dolor" appears under the image and not just "dolor"? I'm using bootstrap, is there any special `<div>` class dedicated to this thing? putting text in `container` or `content` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is helpful.

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#09845A, #8733DD);
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:728px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
  }
  .img {
  background:url("https://www.google.pl/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  width:100px;
}
}

.img {
  background:url("https://www.google.pl/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  height:92px;
  width:272px;
}
.container-fluid {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
}

.container {
  display:block;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">  
  
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="img"></div>
      <h1>
      Ulecz się rozmową
      </h1>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FY3DOVSFM4MZ

basically you need to give col-sm-12 this tells that at smalls screens make this item full width.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using columns instead like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">  
   <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <img src="https://image.com"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h1>lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
</div>   
</div>
```